# Core dump file analysis

Tags: gdb, coredump

What are all the things I will need to check while analyzing a core dump file?

Please tell me from scratch.

Comment: Can you describe what your problem is. What command is giving trouble? Maybe reference the chapter from the doc: http://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html

Answer (score 413):

You just need a binary (with debugging symbols included) that is identical to the one that generated the core dump file. Then you can run `gdb path/to/the/binary path/to/the/core/dump/file` to debug it.

When it starts up, you can use `bt` (for backtrace) to get a stack trace from the time of the crash. In the backtrace, each function invocation is given a number. You can use `frame number` (replacing *number* with the corresponding number in the stack trace) to select a particular stack frame.

You can then use `list` to see code around that function, and `info locals` to see the local variables. You can also use `print name_of_variable` (replacing "name_of_variable" with a variable name) to see its value.

Typing `help` within GDB will give you a prompt that will let you see additional commands.

Comment: Its possible to run `gdb path/to/the/binary path/to/the/core` when coredumped app is not compiled with `-g` flag, but `path/to/the/binary` is same version app, but with -g flag?

Comment: I tried the `bt` command, but it says `no stack`. The core file is large (`ulimit -c unlimited`). What could I be missing?

Comment: @EOL, you might missed the binary as the first argument, and only provided coredump file.

Comment: What if I have no glue what binary produced a core dump? Can I investigate with the `strings` command which binary I need to debug it?

Comment: Oh I can run `file core.86234` and it states which command was used.

Comment: How can I debug a core file (generated on target) on host? How can I give the path of source files on host?

Answer (score 140):

### Steps to debug coredump using GDB:

Some generic help:

**gdb** start GDB, with no debugging les

**gdb program** begin debugging program

**gdb program core** debug coredump core produced by program

**gdb --help** describe command line options

1. First of all, find the directory where the corefile is generated.
2. Then use `ls -ltr` command in the directory to find the latest generated corefile.
3. To load the corefile use

   ```
   gdb binary path of corefile
   ```

   This will load the corefile.
4. Then you can get the information using the `bt` command.

   **For a detailed backtrace use `bt full`.**
5. To print the variables, use `print variable-name` or `p variable-name`
6. To get any help on GDB, use the `help` option or use **`apropos search-topic`**
7. Use `frame frame-number` to go to the desired frame number.
8. Use `up n` and `down n` commands to select frame n frames up and select frame n frames down respectively.
9. To stop GDB, use `quit` or `q`.

Comment: 1- First of all find the directory where the corefile is generated. How to locate this, not able to find the location. Thanks

Comment: Refer these URLs for core dump location :

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192716/how-to-set-the-core-dump-file-location-and-name

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065912/core-dumped-but-core-file-is-not-in-current-directory

Comment: What do you mean by *"with no debugging les"*?

Comment: This is a great explanation but could you explain how we could analyze core dump(Generated from nondebuggable binary)?

Comment: I learnt `bt full` here ;)