# stays on same breakpoint when liteide step over pressed many times

Tags: go, gdb, liteide

When I set a breakpoint in LiteIDE. When the breakpoint is hit. However, the code will stayed on the same breakpoint  when I pressed step over many times. In the aync record, I found the  Stopped->core number is changed when I pressed step over many times. So why Go stay on the same breakpoint many times and what is the "core" represented in async record of liteide?

Thanks

Comment: It's not go.. its gdb. Also, gdb support isn't the best - so your best bet is probably to write some tests that can confirm your logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [this tutorial](http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2014/06/debugging-golang-using-liteide-on-ubuntu-14-04/) in order to see if LiteIDE was properly configured with gdb in order to enable Go debugging session

> To make sure the (GDB based) step-by-step debugger works you need to do the following:
>
> `Build -> Build Configuration... -> Custom -> BUILDARGS` -> Enter: `-gcflags "-N -l"`
>
> Verify everything is working correctly by executing the following debug run:
>
> - `File -> Open Folder -> Click: hello -> Choose`
> - Double click "`for.go`" in the "Folders" pane
> - `Build -> Build` (Ctrl-B)
> - Put cursor on line 19
> - F9 (toggle breakpoint)
> - F5 (start debugging)
> - F5 (until green arrow is on line 19)
> - Debug pane should show "Variables" tab with "i=4" and "j=7"

---

"core" generally refers to a [core dump](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5115613/6309), so  check if your program doesn't crash at this point, generating a core dump.