# Can I get the reason to my application crash, when the app was not run from the gdb?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

I have run my app for several hours, and it has crashed. (c++ app, on LINUX os)

I know that when running app via gdb, we can get the line code & reason of the crash.
But unfortunately I forgot to run it via gdb :(
Is there a way to get the reason of the crash ?

Comment: Was it a debug build, do you have a core file, and do you have symbols? If so (hopefully) [see this question/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115613/core-dump-file-analysis).

Comment: You should enable core dumps (e.g. with `ulimit -c` in the bash shell where you run the app).

Answer (score 3):

You can enable unlimited core dump sizes by

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

This will write down a core file in case of a crash into the same directory from where you started the program. Afterwards you can load it with the `gdb` option `--core`.