# How to analyse a coredump file of GDB

Tags: gdb

How to analyse a coredump file of GDB.

Comment: Another interview question? Stop it.

Comment: If you can't answer,Please you stop it.

Comment: Exactly how many ways do you imagine a program could "do core dump"?

Comment: I don't know anything about coredump.Explain it if you can.I have heard these words in GDB debugging.Don't know exactly what it is

Comment: This site is here for people who need help. "Name all the ways ..." is not how you ask for help. Perhaps you'd like to go to one of the religious exchange sites, and ask "Names all kinds of sin"? It's the same question.

Comment: Improve your attitude.

Comment: Well, that edit improved the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDB can get you started:

```
$ gdb --help
This is the GNU debugger.  Usage:

    gdb [options] [executable-file [core-file or process-id]]
    gdb [options] --args executable-file [inferior-arguments ...]

[snip extended docs]
```

So, you'll invoke it like this:

```
gdb myprog core
```

GDB will then start in the usual way, but the state will be as if you'd stopped at a breakpoint. You can then use "print", "examine", "list", "backtrace", "up", "down", etc. to investigate what caused the crash.

In fact, you can use any GDB command except "continue", "step", "next", or anything else that requires an actual running program.

Comment: too bookish.any example if you can give>

Comment: Ask a specific question; get a specific answer.

Comment: lemme get free,more specific questions coming on your way.

Comment: (for reference)  [gdb - Core dump file analysis - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115613/core-dump-file-analysis) .