# Is it possible to use gdb run a little code of crash process with core file?

Tags: c++, gdb, coredump

I know gdb is not able to do everything and gdb cannot recover program since system resources are not existed after process crash.

I wonder is it possible to use gdb run a little code of process with coredump file? Theoretically, I just want to run a few lines of assembly code with the process memory snapshot, it looks feasible

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, no, for the reasons you already gave.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/62419146/72178