# Install Nodejs on Ubuntu Server can't unzip tar

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

Trying to install node on AWS Ubuntu server instance. I did it few days before, but today it will not let me unzip the file no matter what!  **You can see the errors in the picture.**

Does anybody know why is it doing this and how could i fix it?

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.9.1/node-v6.9.1.tar.gz
tar-xvf node-v6.9.1.tar.gz
```

[image]

Comment: `tar zxvf node-v6.9.1.tar.gz`, you need `z` to uncompress gzip

Comment: Probably a question for serverfault?

Comment: @ymonad it's likely the file is not complete due to wget crash

Comment: Same thing with -zxvf.

Comment: oops, then try using another command such as `curl` instead of wget

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5115613/251311

Comment: and I forgot that nowadays some `tar` command won't need `z` to extract `tar.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround i installed node with curl using these exact 2 commands
[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```