# How find specific file for core dump

Tags: c++, c++11, gdb, coredump

I have 10 files in my current directory and there is core dump occurred due to one file only. How do I find this particular file?
Is there any command for this in gdb?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115613/core-dump-file-analysis

Comment: I know the steps to follow for core dump analysis but Need to know the is there any way so in Production where we have multiple files are there so we can find the file which is responsible for core dump?? @nahzor

Answer (score 0):

> I have 10 files in my current directory and there is core dump occurred due to one file only

The question you *probably* are asking: there are multiple executables and a core dump. How can I find out which executable produced the core?

Running `file core` may or may not answer that question (the first 16 characters of program invocation are easily available, but this doesn't work well when the program is invoked with `/long/path/to/the/binary`).

If you are on a recent Linux, `readelf -n core` may have `NT_FILE` note that will list full paths to the binary and all shared libraries.

Otherwise, running `strings core` usually allows one to guess which program produced it.