# Making sense of a core dump file

Tags: debugging, x86, gdb, disassembly, coredump

Related:

- [How do I analyze a program's core dump file with GDB when it has command-line parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305866/how-do-i-analyze-a-programs-core-dump-file-with-gdb-when-it-has-command-line-pa)
- [Core dump file analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115613/core-dump-file-analysis)

---

What are the most common ways to debug a core dump file? The two ways that I have tried are using `readelf`:

```
$ readelf core -a
```

And then using `gdb`:

```
$ gdb file core
```

However, with gdb I don't get much information (at least not that I can make sense of). For example it shows:

```
Reading symbols from file...
(No debugging symbols found in file)
[New LWP 46778]
Core was generated by `./file'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000000000040100a in ?? ()
>>> bt
#0  0x000000000040100a in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007ffe342c3cbe in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

What sense can someone make of that though? What would be an example of how the `core` file could be used to make sense of something?

Comment: *(No debugging symbols found in file)* - so GDB doesn't have any symbol names, perhaps because you stripped the binary or didn't make any of your asm symbol names `global`.  You can only look at register values and bytes in memory, and disassemble code.  (And get a backtrace with numeric addresses).

Comment: @PeterCordes I see so basically a core file dumped from hand-written assembly without the corresponding DWARF is pretty useless for debugging, right?

Comment: Hardly.  It was written by hand in asm so presumably you can understand how the program works by looking at the disassembly (maybe by looking at the commented source in another window).  `layout reg` should still work, as should `disas`.  You basically have access to everything you would if you ran the program inside GDB until it stopped on a SIGSEGV or whatever.  You just can't single-step, rewind, or set a breakpoint earlier and restart.