# How to analyze a core dump file in fedora

Tags: linux, debugging, coredump

I have a app which crashed and core dump file generated in "/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2022-03-04-08:35:49-11228/coredump"
I ran my application from directory path
/home/MYPC/Development/myPc/src/build/SimUT/x86_64-DEV_PC/Release/bin

I want to know how can I analyze the coredump and backtrace to identify the stack flow.

IS it possible to do this using GDB, What command I need to use.
I am using Fedora for development. Sorry for very generic question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Core dump file analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115613/core-dump-file-analysis)

Comment: Thanks ITs working now :)

Answer (score 2):

On Fedora to debug most resent crush you can just do next command in Terminal:

```
coredumpctl gdb
```