# how to read the content of cpu registers from a core dump file

Tags: c, linux, coredump

I wrote the following C programm

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void main(){

  char *variable = "CodeName0...";
  while (1){
    
    printf("%s\n%d\n","hello from gencore code source",getpid());

    sleep(2);
  }
  exit(0);
}
```

after running it I sent a SIGABRT signal using the following command
`kill -6 <process Id from code execution>`

this generated a core dump file under the name `core` inside the same directory

I want to read the content of cpu registers ( IP ... ) but I didn't manage to do it

I'm runnig parrot OS, this is the output of `uname -a`

`Linux Parrot 5.16.0-12parrot1-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 5.16.12-2parrot1 (2022-03-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I tried using gdb but I'm getting this error

`"0x7fffd7f6de10s": not in executable format: file format not recognized`

I would like to know why this is the case ( file format not recognized )

Comment: How do you execute `gdb` ?

Comment: I use `coredumpctl` so for me it was just `coredumpctl debug` and then it started `gdb` just fine and `info all-registers` showed all registers. How did you do it?

Comment: @EugeneSh  I ran `gdb core`  I believe I was doing it wrong. does gdb take the state of the program execution as an argument?

Comment: You could search and find out it quite easily. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115613/core-dump-file-analysis

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm not able to install systemd-coredump on my system because of dependencies problem, I'm getting `systemd-coredump : Depends: systemd (= 247.3-7+deb11u1) but 251.3-1~bpo11+1 is to be installed` where can I find the ` systemd 247.3-7+deb11u1` package?

Comment: What about `gdb your_executable core`?

Comment: that worked `gdb <executable> <core>` . Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure how to explain it any further:

```
$ gdb <binary> <core>
i all-registers
```

where `<binary>` is your binary, ideally compiled with -g3, and `<core>` is your core file that was dumped.  You may need to navigate to different frame (`bt` and `f <number>` where `<number> is the frame number).`  all-registers is a little verbose but here is `i register` output:

```
rax            0xfffffffffffffdfc  -516
rbx            0xffffffffffffff80  -128
rcx            0x7fa81f0c650a      140360052139274
rdx            0x7ffc19fe2020      140720744570912
rsi            0x0                 0
rdi            0x0                 0
rbp            0x0                 0x0
rsp            0x7ffc19fe1fe0      0x7ffc19fe1fe0
r8             0x0                 0
r9             0x27                39
r10            0x7ffc19fe2020      140720744570912
r11            0x246               582
r12            0x562d5cc38070      94752829833328
r13            0x0                 0
r14            0x0                 0
r15            0x0                 0
rip            0x7fa81f0c650a      0x7fa81f0c650a <__GI___clock_nanosleep+42>
eflags         0x246               [ PF ZF IF ]
cs             0x33                51
ss             0x2b                43
ds             0x0                 0
es             0x0                 0
fs             0x0                 0
gs             0x0                 0
```