# how to debug using "*.stackdump" file in cygwin

Tags: segmentation-fault, cygwin, stack-dump

I am newbie on cygwin(and linux).

When I tried to run my executable file based on C language, segmentation fault occured, and I take stackdump file. but, I don't know how to use it for debugging.

I have been searching for the way how to debug using stackdump file, but I cound't find it.
Any small tips are very useful to me. thanks for reading my poor english (english is not my 1st language).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320001/using-a-stackdump-from-cygwin-executable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**First**: you need to compile your program passing to gcc the flag `-ggdb` otherwise the stackdump info is useless. I suggest to pass also the `-O0` flag so that debugging with gdb will be more easy as the code will not be optimized.

**Second**: the stackdump provide the addresses present in the stack,
in this example on 32bit we have two addresses:

```
$ cat t-invmod.exe.stackdump
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
0028C878  61032BCB (000000F4, 0000EA60, 000000A4, 0028C8D8)
0028C998  610E7A7A (00000001, 0028CA3F, 00000001, 611A2C80)
```

The address can be coming from your programs or from loaded shared libs.

To convert the address to code position, use `addr2line`.
Example:

```
$ addr2line.exe -a 610E7A7A -a 61032BCB -e /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll 
0x610e7a7a
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-2.5.1-1/winsup/cygwin/cygerrno.h:36
0x61032bcb
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-2.5.1-1/winsup/cygwin/cygerrno.h:35
```

In this case the high address told me that the crash was in a shared lib and not in the program. You can use `ldd` to identify to what the addresses belong:

```
$ ldd t-invmod.exe
        ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SysWOW64/ntdll.dll (0x776d0000)
        kernel32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/kernel32.dll (0x75500000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/KERNELBASE.dll (0x75a10000)
        SYSFER.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SysWOW64/SYSFER.DLL (0x73480000)
        cygflint.dll => /usr/bin/cygflint.dll (0x5f390000)
        cygwin1.dll => /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll (0x61000000)
        cyggmp-10.dll => /usr/bin/cyggmp-10.dll (0x589e0000)
        cygmpfr-4.dll => /usr/bin/cygmpfr-4.dll (0x51080000)
        cyggcc_s-1.dll => /usr/bin/cyggcc_s-1.dll (0x5ece0000)
        cygntl-9.dll => /usr/bin/cygntl-9.dll (0x50270000)
        cygstdc++-6.dll => /usr/bin/cygstdc++-6.dll (0x4b340000)
```

If the address is lower than dll's one, it belongs to your program; If it belongs to shared lib you need to installl the relative *debuginfo package for recovering the location information.